# Networking - prioritise wifi over ethernet

Tags: wireless, network-manager, ethernet, network-bridge

Ok, quick summary of what I want to do:

- My Wi-Fi subnet (my router to the internet is on this subnet) exists on `192.168.1.x`
- I'm also trying to do some work on a wired Ethernet network on the same `192.168.1.x` subnet, that doesn't have access to the internet.

If I connect via ethernet to the second network via my eth0 interface I lose access to the internet.

Is there any way I can keep it? I don't really care if the  ethernet devices can't connect to the internet through my pc, I just want to be able to connect to them  but still be able to access the internet.

Maybe it will be simpler if it's broken down into specific ip addresses? My wifi interface  only needs access to 2 other devices (let's say `192.168.1.10`  & `192.168.1.11`) while my Ethernet interface only needs access to ONE device (let's say `192.168.1.200`)

Currently my WLAN is set to `192.168.1.10` &  my eth0 is set to `192.168.1.250`